# select statement immediately returning instead of waiting for user activity or socket activity

Tags: c++, select

I am making a simple game client. This client needs to handle messages from the server and the user input (in this game the only input is keyboard presses). The user NEVER hits enter which I think may be causing the problem but I am not sure. Here is the relevant code:

```
FD_ZERO(&readfds);
FD_ZERO(&writefds);
FD_CLR(0,&readfds);
FD_SET(c.retsock(),&readfds); // socket
FD_SET(0, &readfds); // reads standard input
cout << "waiting for activity..\n";
check = select(NULL, &readfds, &writefds, NULL, NULL);
if(FD_ISSET(0, &readfds)){
  cout << "User pressed key\n";
  gett = wait_for_key_typed();
  cout << "After waiting for key typed\n";
```

In my program the select statement doesn't wait at all. Instead, it immediately jumps into the case where the file descriptor "0" was the "ready" file descriptor.

Also, the wait_for_key_typed() just waits for a user to press a key and reads what it was once they do. This does not wait for the user to enter. Aside from that, I do not know how it works. I did not write it.

If you know another way of grabbing user input without pressing enter that would be very nice as well.
Thank you for any help you can give!

Comment: This is being run on windows. Windows ignores the first parameter of select which is why I have it as NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to `select()` is not a pointer, so `NULL` is not a legal value. Unless you're running on Windows, neither is zero.

Comment: I am running on windows. According to the windows documentation I found select() ignores the first parameter when run in windows. That's why I have it as NULL

Comment: Yes, but windows ignores it so the compiler doesn't realize it doesn't make sense. 

I figured out the issue: windows only allows you to use select with sockets, not stdin. 

Thank you for your help, though. I really appreciate it!

Comment: It's the wrong type. On some architectures that could result in passing the wrong width of zero. Don't just ignore this issue. It's real.

Answer (score 0):

I FIGURED OUT THE ISSUE

Windows only allows you to use select() with sockets, not stdin like you can in UNIX systems.

It doesnt wait because "0" is not a proper file descriptor like it is in UNIX.